# Unable to connect to EC2 + Elastic IP

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am setting up a Rest API on AWS EC2 and configuring the instance.

I have a problem and it is that despite being able to connect via ssh, I cannot make an API call on port 5000.
The VM has nothing configured, only Node and PM2.

Trying to enter through the public DNS I can't establish a connection either.

I have these security groups enabled.

```
5000    TCP 0.0.0.0/0   
22      TCP 0.0.0.0/0   
5000    TCP ::/0        
443     TCP 0.0.0.0/0   
443     TCP ::/0    
80      TCP 0.0.0.0/0   
80      TCP ::/0
```

Can someone help me with this? I don't understand what is happening.

Comment: Make sure you are using `http://<your-ip>:5000` in your browser. Your browser likes to use `https` by default, and you probably don't have SSL set up yet.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi I have tried it but no success. I am also trying to make the connection from postman and there is no way.

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact error is it timing out ?

If yes then the error is with the security group if not try doing ssh to your container and ping it locally using curl localhost command you might  find that the pm2 server is not running the app properly

Comment: Hi. When I curl localhost from the same ec2 console, it returns: Failed to connect to localhost port80: Connection refused.

Comment: @ToniSanchez, what applications are running ? What do you get when you do `netstat -ntlp`?

Comment: Yes then your server is not working internally no problems with your DNS routing 
check your pm2 configuration and make it work locally on ec2